# why can't we run perl cgi-scripts using python server i.e simpleHTTPServer?

Tags: python, perl, cgi-bin

why do we need apache web server to run cgi scripts? Can it be done using python simpleHTTPServer

Comment: Why would you expect a Python server to be able to run Perl scripts?

Comment: Why do you think that you need Apache to run CGI programs?

Comment: Why do you want to run CGI scripts in 2015 when you can have e.g. [plack](http://plackperl.org/)?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need apache, but you need a server implementing the [CGI specification](http://www.w3.org/CGI/). Most trivial servers don't because that's not the use case they are developed for. But it should be possible to use the python implementation [CGIHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html).